# Replace Bootstrap checkboxes with Material checkboxes in a Bootstrap web app

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, material-design, mdbootstrap

I have a web app all developed with a Bootstrap theme, now I would want to replace just the checkboxes inside the application with those coming from mdbootstrap, basically a [Material Checkbox](https://mdbootstrap.com/components/bootstrap-checkbox/).

Is that possible to load just the part of the CSS related to the checkboxes and not all the rest?

Is there any other way to have just the Material checkboxes in a bootstrap theme ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. What you have to do is copy all of the relevant `css` from Material website into your own stylesheets. If you inspect element, you'll notice that all styles related to checkboxes revolve around `.form-check` class.

[image]

Once you copy all of the styles, rename them to match bootstrap's naming convention.